# Is "I was least expecting it from you" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm about to write a tongue-lash for someone who let me down quite badly and I want to be grammatically correct. So, how should I say this:

"**I was least expecting** this kind of cynical criticism from you..."

or

"**I least expected** this kind of cynical criticism from you..."

Other suggestions are also welcome. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Neither is strictly wrong and that's not what this forum is for.

If you need to, why not run your tongue-lash past a spelling or grammar checker?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for **Mate**:

**Least expected** refers to something that is the **least likely** (or most unlikely) to happen.

Similarly, or rather, conversely:
**Least unexpected** refers to something that is the least unlikely (or **most likely**) to happen. I add this, as they tend to be used interchangeably sometimes, however, the above is the correct usage.

Although I am sure that the scathing message is very likely to have been sent already, approximately 6 years ago, on the off-chance that you may need to use similar phrasing in the future I will provide you with some other suggestions to convey the same meaning:

(The following two sentences you will certainly recognise as your own, but I will be numbering them to compare and contrast implied meaning).

1. "**I was least expecting** this kind of cynical criticism from you..."
2. "**I least expected** this kind of cynical criticism from you..."
3. "**I was least expectant** of this kind of cynical criticism from you..."
4. "**Least of all did I expect** you to give this kind of cynical criticism..."

So from the examples above, both 1 and 2 convey different tenses.

From nationalarchives.gov.uk - "To describe a past action or state which is incomplete, we use an imperfect tense. This tense indicates an action which has gone on over a period time or has happened frequently. It is translated into English by 'was/were' + '-ing' or 'used to'."

Calling this tense "imperfect" is a little outdated now so it is more commonly referred to as the "past continuous" tense, which I personally find to be a more explanatory name for this tense. The Past Continuous tense can be exemplified by the phrase "I was doing", and thus implies that there is a lacking "until...".

In your example, 1 would imply that, as Max Williams said, you previously **would have been** least expectant of this person's criticism... **until, over time,** you saw their true colours. This is a more emotional option and of the two examples you gave I would have chosen this one, as it gives the sense that you held trust and hope with this person **until** you were criticised so deeply.

Example 2 shows the simple past tense. As it implies, it is simple. It is a statement of fact, it's rather cold, not in the sense of emotionally cold, but moreso in that it lacks nuance. It just presents the statement made as a plain fact. If you were going for a cold and distant approach, this would have been an option, but as you said it was a *scathing* message, I will assume you wanted the recipient to feel the raw emotion of your anger or pain. If this example were used, ffor lack of decent phrasing, it would be a conceptual equivalent of "yeah man, I mean, I didn't expect you to be so critical of me because I thought we were chill, but it's not that deep, because that's in the past now and these days you're irrelevant to how i live my life" (please read that, and then imagine a formal equivalent of that sentence- one that expresses nonchalance to the point of disinterest)

So I would say it depends how it affected you.

For example 3, I am aware it sounds Shakespearean, however it is technically more sound.

So, the only difference between example 1 and example 3 is that 1 uses "**expecting**" (a verb) and example 3 uses "**expectant**" (an adverb).

I **(noun)** was **(past tense verb)** -- least **(adverb)** expectant **(adverb)** -- (**both** of these adverbs **together** make an **adverbial**, or an adverb that modifies an adverb). The adverbial in this case is therefore further describing the verb "to be" or in the past tense, "was", meaning that the mannerism or emotion carried at that continuous time in the past (throughout the time you knew this person) was one of not being able to fathom the thought of and to have been caught unexpectedly off guard by the person's betrayal and criticism of you.

Answer (score -1):

You could use either, but the first one has more of an implication that your opinion of the person **has changed** - in other words, you had previously least expected it from them, but that's no longer the case: now you **would** expect it from them.